# Sockets and while loops

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

1) Question: are both while loops runing at the same time? What i want to know is the while loop in main() method runing while while loop in sendDATA is being executed ?

2) If not how can i send and receive at the same time. I have to implement TFTP so i have to read and send 512 bytes per packet so: I read 512 bytes and send them then wait for ACK packet to arrive from client ACK Packet = |opcode|block#| so incoming[0] = 3 and incoming[1] = int block #

If the block # number in incoming matches the one i sent then i can send the next packet if not i must send the previus one. I dont know how to implement this with one loop.

My code:

```
package source;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server
{


    static String[] errorcodes = {"Not defined", "File not found", "Access violation", "Disk full or allocation exceeded", "Illegal TFTP Operation",
                              "Unknown transfer ID", "File already exists", "No such user"}; 

    static String FILE = "";
    static String MODE = "";

    static byte[] outgoing = new byte[512];
    static byte[] incoming = new byte[512];

    static DatagramSocket socket;

    static String clientip;
    static int clientport;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {   
        socket = new DatagramSocket(13373); // 69 Reserved for TFTP

        // Listen for incoming packets
        while(true) {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(incoming, incoming.length);
            socket.receive(packet);

            clientip = packet.getAddress().toString().replace("/", "");
            clientport = packet.getPort();

            System.out.println(clientport);

            if(incoming[0] == 1 || incoming[0] == 2) {
                handleRequest(incoming);
            }

        }
    }

    // sends DATA opcode = 3 : | opcode | block # | data |
    private static void sendDATA() {
        outgoing = new byte[512]; // Empty array
        try {
            ByteBuffer sDATA = ByteBuffer.allocate(516);
            // 512 - 2 byte opcode, 2 byte block #, 512 data

            DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(outgoing, outgoing.length, InetAddress.getByName(clientip), clientport);
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE));

            int a;
            int block = 1;



            while((a = fis.read(outgoing,0,512)) != -1)
            {
                data.setLength(a);
                sDATA.put((byte)3);
                sDATA.put((byte)block);
                sDATA.put(outgoing);
                socket.send(data);

                if(incoming[0] == 3 && incoming[1] == block) 
                {

                }

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }


    // Request packet: | opcode | filename | 0 | mode | 0 |
    // Upravlja le z WRQ / RRQ opcode
    private static void handleRequest(byte[] packet) 
    {

        int opcode = packet[0];
        String filename = "";
        int offset = 0;
        String mode = "";

        // Get filename
        for(int i = 1; i < packet.length; i++) {
            if(packet[i] != 0) {
                filename += (char)packet[i];
            } else {
                offset = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Get mode
        for(int j =  offset; j < packet.length; j++) {
            if(packet[j] != 0) {
                mode += (char)packet[j];
            }
        }
        FILE = filename;
        MODE = mode;
        if(opcode == 1) {
            // Do RRQ
            File test = new File(filename);
            if(test.exists()) {
                sendACK(); 
            } else {
                sendERROR(1);
            }
        } else {
            // Do WRQ
            File test2 = new File(filename);
            if(test2.exists()) {
                sendERROR(6);
            } else {
                sendACK();
            }
        }
    }


    // send ACK opcode = 4 : | opcode | block # |
    // block 0 -> prvi ACK, odgovor na RRQ/WRQ 
    // block 1 -> stevilo poslanega bloka, stetje blokov se zacne
    // pri 1.
    private static void sendACK() {
        outgoing = new byte[512];
        outgoing[0] = (byte)4;
        outgoing[1] = (byte)0;

        try {
            DatagramPacket ackpacket = new DatagramPacket(outgoing, outgoing.length, InetAddress.getByName(clientip), clientport);
            socket.send(ackpacket);
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }   

    // send ERROR packet opcode =  5 : | opcode | errorcode | msg | 0 |
    // General errorcodes: 2
    private static void sendERROR(int errorcode) {
        ByteBuffer errpack = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);
        errpack.put((byte)5); // opcode
        errpack.put((byte)errorcode); // errorcode
        try {
            errpack.put(errorcodes[errorcode].getBytes("US-ASCII")); // msg
            errpack.put((byte)0);

            outgoing = errpack.array(); // Pack ERROR Packet

            DatagramPacket errpacket = new DatagramPacket(outgoing, outgoing.length, InetAddress.getByName(clientip), clientport);
            socket.send(errpacket);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: sendDATA is never called, maybe you need to edit the code sample a little.  Streams block, so you might want to use multiple threads to do multiple things concurrently.

Comment: the reason i didnt call it yet is because its not finished look at what iam asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: are both while loops runing at the same time? What i want to know is the while loop in main() method runing while while loop in sendDATA is being executed ?

No.  But incoming UDP packets are buffered up (to a certain limit) while you are calling handleRequest.  Such that when handleRequest returns, if there is a new UDP packet available, the subsequent call to socket.receive() will return immediately. This doesn't guarantee you won't lose packets if you spend too long in your "handleRequest" call.  But it will likely work for reasonable load and small files.

> If not how can i send and receive at the same time.

You should keep a data structure to hold the state of each session. (e.g. what file is being transferred, how many bytes transferred thus far, ack state, etc...)  Store each session in a collection/list somewhere.  Such that your code logic looks something like this:

```
// this is not java, just pseudo code
while (true)
{
    packet = receive packet from network
    session = list_of_sessions.lookup(packet.fromaddress)
    if (session == null)
    {
        session = new Session(packet)
        list_of_sessions.add(new Session(), packet.fromaddress)
    }
    handleRequest(packet, session); // sends a response based on state or packet received
    if (session.isFinished)
    {
        list_of_sessions.remove(session)    
    }
}
```

The single threaded approach above is likely the best for you. But if you want to get wild, you could invest in threads. I'm not sure if you are ready for that yet.